# deleting object keys which start with a vowel js

Tags: javascript, object

I need to remove all keys, which start with the vowel from an object but I can't figure out how to do it. This is what I have so far. In this example only the 'chip' key should stay and all the others should be removed. Can you guys help me with this?

```
'use strict'

function removeVowelKeys(object) {
  for (let key in object) {
    if (key[0] === 'a' || key[0] === 'A' || key[0] === 'u' || key[0] === 'U' ||
    key[0] === 'i' || key[0] === 'I' || key[0] === 'o' || key[0] === 'O' ||
    key[0] === 'e' || key[0] === 'E' || key[0] === 'y' || key[0] === 'Y' ) {
      delete object.key
  }
}
}


console.log(removeVowelKeys({
  alarm: 'This is SPARTA!!!',
  chip: 100,
  isValid: false,
  Advice: 'Learn it hard',
  onClick: 'make it great again',
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return your object from your function, but also you shouldn't delete keys from the object as you're looping over it.

Something like this will do it:

```js
const removeVowelKeys = (obj) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(
      ([k]) => !["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(k.toLowerCase()[0])
     )
  );

console.log(removeVowelKeys({
  alarm: 'This is SPARTA!!!',
  chip: 100,
  isValid: false,
  Advice: 'Learn it hard',
  onClick: 'make it great again',
}));
```

I also fixed up your original method to copy the object before iterating over it and also using `[square bracket]` notation to use your keys correctly:

```
function removeVowelKeys(obj) {
  for (let key in { ...obj }) {
    if (
      key[0] === "a" ||
      key[0] === "A" ||
      key[0] === "u" ||
      key[0] === "U" ||
      key[0] === "i" ||
      key[0] === "I" ||
      key[0] === "o" ||
      key[0] === "O" ||
      key[0] === "e" ||
      key[0] === "E" ||
      key[0] === "y" ||
      key[0] === "Y"
    ) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I went about it.
Make sure that you actually return something from your function...
Also note that y is not technically a vowel.

```js
function removeVowelKeys(obj) {
    let output = {};
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (!(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(key[0].toLowerCase()))) output[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return output;
}
```